# How to SUM with COUNT function wih conditions

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

**Here my table:**

```
id | marital_stat |
====================
1      divorced 
2      divorced 
3      married 
4      single
```

I want to seperate the sums of each marital status, I'm using condition because in my tables using `varchar` not `integer`.

**Here is my queries in my Model file:**

```
SELECT
COUNT(CASE WHEN marital = 'divorced'   THEN 1 END) AS divorcestat,
COUNT(CASE WHEN marital = 'married' THEN 1 END) AS marriedstat,
COUNT(CASE WHEN marital = 'single' THEN 1 END) AS singlestat
FROM status_tbl
```

With the query above produces the value that I want, the results was:

```
    divorcestat | marriedstat | singlestat
--------------------------------------------
    2               1              1
```

But now I need to add up all the values above and will produce as a `Total`, `(divorcestat+marriedstat+singlestat) -> Total` from the `Count` functions. How do I do that?I've tried some answer in stackoverflow but nothing worked. `Group by, Union`, just not working.

Answer (score 2):

You can use count(*)

```
SELECT
COUNT(CASE WHEN marital = 'divorced'   THEN 1 END) AS divorcestat,
COUNT(CASE WHEN marital = 'married' THEN 1 END) AS marriedstat,
COUNT(CASE WHEN marital = 'single' THEN 1 END) AS singlestat,
COUNT(*) AS Total 
FROM status_tbl
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `count(*)` to the query

```
SELECT
COUNT(CASE WHEN marital = 'divorced'   THEN 1 END) AS divorcestat,
COUNT(CASE WHEN marital = 'married' THEN 1 END) AS marriedstat,
COUNT(CASE WHEN marital = 'single' THEN 1 END) AS singlestat,
COUNT(*) AS total_stat
FROM status_tbl;
```

I hope that helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a "table expression" to reuse the values you have already computed.

For example:

```
select
  *,
  divorcestat + marriedstat + singlestat as total
from (
  SELECT
  COUNT(CASE WHEN marital = 'divorced'   THEN 1 END) AS divorcestat,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN marital = 'married' THEN 1 END) AS marriedstat,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN marital = 'single' THEN 1 END) AS singlestat
  FROM status_tbl
) x
```

This can come in handy when the expression you use to compute values are complex and you don't want to repeat them in your query.